# Novice question on the fundementals of multiplication/division in any equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In basic math we learn that we can divide out a variable that is multiplied by any number on both sides of an equation like so:

$2x=9x^2$ for $\frac {2x} x = \frac {9x^2} x $ then $2=9x$

My question is ver simple, if we can do what is in the example above then why can't we do this exact same process when the coefficient of the divided variable is equal to 1? for instance:

$x=9x^2$ for  $\frac {1x} x = \frac {9x^2} x$ then $1=9x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.  Then $x = \frac{1}{9}$. One problem is that you've effectively removed a solution.  Remember, you can only divide if $x \neq 0$, so by dividing, you're removing that solution. Actually checking the equation, you can see that $x = 0$ *is* also a solution. Note that to avoid this, we can say $$x = 9x^2$$ So$$ 9x^2 - x = 0$$ and $$ x(9x - 1) = 0$$

So we have solutions when either of those terms is equal to $0$, which happens at $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{1}{9}$.  We do it this way so we don't accidentally "remove" a solution like $x = 0$.

Comment: So I can conclude that this method is incorrect because it removes solutions to the problem.

Comment: Also I just realized that what I had above would work. However what if the problem was like this:

Comment: $x=0$ for $ \frac 1 x = \frac 0 x$ then $1=0$ which is incorrect

Comment: Any time you end up dividing by $0$, then you have an incorrect solution, and the universe will explode.  If you start off with $x = 0$, it doesn't make sense to turn that into $1 = \frac{0}{x}$, because the act of dividing $0$ by $x$ is undefined--you've already declared that $x = 0$. If instead of that, you mean that you start with $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{0}{x}$, well, you'll never start with that, because that very equation implies that $0 = 1$, since they're equal when divided by the same thing, which is certainly not true.

Comment: Hahah so by the rules of mathematics it works, however by the rules of logic and common sense, a statement implying that 1(0r any other #) = 0 is an false statement and the universe will explode.

Comment: Even by the rules of mathematics it's not valid.  We call $\frac{1}{x}$ the multiplicative inverse of $x$, and the multiplicative inverse of a number $a$ is defined as the number $a^{-1}$ such that $(a)(a^{-1}) = 1$, and this number **only** exists if $a \neq 0$.  If $a = 0$, then it does not have a multiplicative inverse.  In our case, we have $x = 0$, so it does not have a multiplicative inverse, so it doesn't make *sense* to say $\frac{1}{x}$ -- this number simply does not exist. Can you see why $x$ doesn't have an inverse? No matter what you multiply $0$ by, it will always be $0$, not $1$.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thank you for taking the time to explain such simple concepts to me Alex.